# "Ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" when combining inner classes, existential types, IndexedSeq, and def

Tags: scala

I have some Scala code I cannot get to compile, and I simplified it down to what appears to be the essence of the problem.

```
class Inner[T] {
  class Value
  val values = IndexedSeq.empty[Value]
}

class Outer[T] {
  def inner = new Inner[T]
}

object TestApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val outer: Outer[_] = null
    val values = outer.inner.values
    values(0)
  }
}
```

I am using 2.9.1.final

```
$ scalac test.scala 
test.scala:14: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method apply in trait SeqLike of type ((idx: Int)Inner[_$1]#Value) forSome { type _$1 }
and  method apply in trait Function1 of type ((v1: Int)Inner[_$1]#Value) forSome { type _$1; type _$1; type _$1 }
match argument types (Int)
    values(0)
    ^
one error found
```

I am able to make the compilation error go away if I do any of the following:

- Remove inner classes (`IndexedSeq.empty[String]` instead of `IndexedSeq.empty[Value]`)
- Remove existential types (`Outer[String]` instead of `Outer[_]`)
- Remove IndexedSeq.apply (`values.head` instead of `values(0)`)
- Change `def inner` to `val inner` (this is the most puzzling one)

Unfortunately in my use case, I can't change any of those (it's not evident why in this small example, but the actual code relies on them being that way). Am I doing something forbidden, or is this a limitation of the compiler?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a limitation since it seems fine in `2.10.0-M4`.

Of course it gives a `NullPointer` though since `outer` is set to `null`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll see if I can try it in the milestone and report back. (Yeah null pointer expected in this code extract.)

Comment: I notice 2.10 gives the warning "test.scala:13: warning: inferred existential type IndexedSeq[Inner[_$1]#Value] forSome { type _$1 }, which cannot be expressed by wildcards,  should be enabled
by making the implicit value language.existentials visible." Do you think there's a way to explicitly type this and may that would resolve it in 2.9 as well?

Comment: Looks like splitting `val values = outer.inner.values` into `val inner = outer.inner; val values = inner.values` did the trick in 2.9